# Python struct.pack() behavior

Tags: python-2.7

```
data = 5 
Result1 = struct.pack("<L", data)
```

1. The integer data is converted to long (64bit). that is `01000000 00010100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`?
2. Then the bits are reversed as bytes and stored in `Result1` as byte strings?. that is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010100 01000000`

is this what exactly happens with that code or did I misunderstood anything?

Comment: `print repr(Result1)` (after it's initialized) and you'll see what actually happens.

Comment: `@CristiFati` with data `5` it's `'\x05\x00\x00\x00'` and with data `55555` it's `'\x03\xd9\x00\x00'` so, these are bytestrings? so what exactly that code did to get these byte-strings? did it read `55555` as integer and converted to `bytes` ? those seems like hex numbers with `/x` prefix but I still don't understand what happens inside it, how did the code calculated that `'\x03'` for example? I really need to do this manually step by step.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

From [[Python 2.Docs]: struct - Interpret bytes as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct):

> This module performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python strings.

This means that it will print the memory representation of the argument(s) as *char* sequences. Memory (and everything that resides in it) is a sequence of bytes. Each byte has a value *[0..255]* (for simplicity's sake I use *unsigned*). 
So, when it will represent a byte, it will first search for a *char* having the *ASCII* code matching the byte value, and if such a (*printable*) *char* is found, it will be the representation of that byte, otherwise the representation will be the byte value (in *hex*) preceded by ***\x*** (convention for representing non printable *char*s). As a side note, (non extended) *ASCII* *char*s have values between *0* and *128*.

Example:

- A byte value of ***65*** (*hex* ***0x41***) will be represented as '**A**' (as **A**'s *ASCII* code is ***65***)
- A byte value of ***217*** (*hex* ***0xd9***) will be simply represented as '***\xd9***' (there's no printable *char* with this *ASCII* code)

Before going further, a few words are needed about **endianness**: that is the way how data (numbers in our case) is represented in computer memory. A couple of links (although many resources can be found on the internet):

- [[Wikipedia]: Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)
- [[UMD.CS]: Big and Little Endian](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html)

I'll try to briefly explain the difference between *big* and *little endian* (again, for simplicity's sake I'll stick with the *8 bit atomic* element size only).

Imagine we're doing some memory representation exercises on a piece of paper, or better: on a blackboard. If we were to represent the blackboard as the computer memory, then the upper left corner would be its beginning (address ***0***) and the addresses would increase as we go to the right (and also down below to the next line when we reach the right edge).
We want to represent the number ***0x12345678*** as a *4* byte number, starting from the upper left corner (each byte consists of **exactly *2*** hex digits):

> ```
> ╔═══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
> ║   Byte    ║    01    ║    02    ║    03    ║    04    ║
> ╠═══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
> ║   Value   ║   0x12   ║   0x34   ║   0x56   ║   0x78   ║
> ╚═══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
> ```

Our number's ***most significant*** byte is stored at the ***lowest*** memory address (and the *least significant byte* is stored at the *highest*), which is **big endian**. For **little endian**, our number bytes are in reversed order.

As a conclusion, humans think "*big endian*ly".

Another topic that I want to cover is: **types** (*int* to be more precise). *Python*, being *C* based, inherits its native types, so an *int* will have *4* bytes (on some platforms / architectures it might have *8*). So, an *int* (again, talking about *unsigned*) has a value *[0..4294967295]*. But even for a smaller value: *5* for example (which only requires *1* byte), it will still occupy *4* bytes: the (most significant) unused bytes will be padded with ***0***s. So, our number as a *4* byte *unsigned int* will be (*hex*): ***0x00000005***.

**Now, back to our problem(s)**: as stated above, ***5*** is ***0x05*** (or ***0x00000005*** - *4* byte *unsigned int*) or in *chars*: "***\x00\x00\x00\x05***". But it's in reversed order than what *struct.pack* displays; I think you already guessed why: it's in *little endian* representation. That is given by the 1<sup>st</sup> (*fmt*) argument ("***<***" part to be more precise) given to [[Python 2.Docs]: struct.**pack**(*fmt, v1, v2, ...*)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) (possible values are listed on the same page: [[Python 2.Docs]: struct - Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)).
For ***55555***, things are just the same. Its *hex* representation is: ***0xd903*** or ***0x0000d903***.

If it doesn't make sense yet, take this slightly modified version of your code and play with it, by entering different values for *data_set* and see the outputs:

*code.py*:

```py
import struct
fmt = "<L"
data_set = [5, 55555, 0x12345678]

for data in data_set:
    output_str = "{} - {}".format(hex(data), repr(struct.pack(fmt, data)).strip("'"))  # This is just for formatting output string to be displayed to the user
    print(output_str)  # Python3 compatible (however the formatting above won't behave nicely)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q037990060>"C:\Install\x64\HPE\OPSWpython\2.7.10__00\python.exe" "code.py"
> 0x5 - \x05\x00\x00\x00
> 0xd903 - \x03\xd9\x00\x00
> 0x12345678 - xV4\x12
> ```