# Receiving binary data through network sockets in python 3

Tags: python, sockets, networking, binary, hex

In my networking class a lab i have is to make a client to receive 5 familiar 32-bit integers in big endian order and to intemperate them. I decided to use python and everything works well enough but i am receiving strange hex code.

> \x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00\xe4\x00\x00\x01\xb3\x00\x00\x01\xdb\x00\x00\x01\xec

I can convert most of it easily but the x00o is really confusing me, 228 435 475 492 where the 4 after that I believe. Can you help me intemperate the server message?

```
import socket 
import sys
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print('Failed to create socket')
    sys.exit()
print('Socket Created')

host = 'localhost'
port = 5071

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)

except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()

s.connect((remote_ip , port))

print('Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip)

reply = s.recv(4096)

print(reply)
```

Comment: If the value of a byte in the buffer corresponds to a printable character, Python shows it as that character when printing the buffer as a string. If the value does not match a printable character, Python shows the byte as two hex digits after a `\x` prefix.  So your `\x00o` represents a byte with value zero followed by a byte whose value is the value of the character 'o'.  The numeric value of that byte is `ord('o')` which is 111 decimal, 6f hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*code.py*:

```
import sys
import struct


def convert_data_to_ints(data, big_endian=True):
    int_count = len(data) // 4  # Assuming uint is 4 bytes long !!!
    fmt = ">" if big_endian else "<"
    fmt += "I" * int_count
    return struct.unpack(fmt, data[:int_count * 4])


def main():
    print("Python {} on {}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    data = b"\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00\xe4\x00\x00\x01\xb3\x00\x00\x01\xdb\x00\x00\x01\xec"
    ints_be = convert_data_to_ints(data)
    print("Big endian: {}".format(ints_be))
    ints_le = convert_data_to_ints(data, big_endian=False)
    print("Little endian: {}".format(ints_le))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- `convert_data_to_ints`:

  - Uses [[Python]: struct.**unpack**(*fmt, buffer*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) to perform the conversion (might also check [[SO]: Python struct.pack() behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990060/python-struct-pack-behavior) for more details on how integers are being represented in memory - and also in the server response)
  - Conversion is done to ***unsigned** int* (`"I"` format). Check the "*Format Strings*" section in on the (1<sup>st</sup>) above page
  - Relies on the fact that *int* is 4 bytes long (I didn't want to hardcode the `"IIIII"`, wanted to make it more general). If the string length is not a multiple of 4 (an integral number of *int*s), the incomplete *int* at the end (at most 3 bytes) is discarded (of course, a nicer way to pad the string and also convert the "incomplete" data, but that's outside the question scope)
  - Returns a tuple containing the converted integers
- `main`:

  - Calls the above function on the data that you received from socket
  - As a bonus, it also converts it using *little endian* (but those values don't make much sense)
  - The data is a [[Python]: Bytes Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) instance (I think `socket.recv` returns it in this form). If (I'm wrong and) it returns the data as a string, just use [[Python]: str.**encode**(*encoding="utf-8", errors="strict"*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)

**Output**:

> ```
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048508018>"c:\install\Python\3.4.3\x86\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>
> Big endian: (111, 228, 435, 475, 492)
> Little endian: (1862270976, 3825205248, 3003187200, 3674275840, 3959488512)
> ```