# Reading a C-struct via sockets into python

Tags: python, c, struct

On an embedded device running a C application, I have defined this struct:

```
struct TestStruct
{
    float first;
    int second;
    char third;
};
```

On request, I send this struct via sockets:

```
else if(strcmp(str, "Get Stru") == 0)
{
    TestStruct testStruct;
    testStruct.first = 1.2;
    testStruct.second = 42;
    testStruct.third = 'A';

    INT32 sendDataLength = send(m_Socket, (char *)(&testStruct), sizeof(testStruct), 0);
}
```

and read it from a Python script on my desktop:

```
import struct
import socket  
from ctypes import *

class YourStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('v', c_float),
                ('t', c_int),
                ('c', c_char)]

s = socket.socket()
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1234

s.connect((host, port))

s.send('Get Stru'.encode())
data = s.recv(20)
print(data)

x = YourStruct()
```

This is the data printed to console on my desktop:

[image]

How can i reassemble the `data` into a `YourStruct`?

Note that the embedded device uses little endian, so I have had to use `struct.unpack("<" + "f" * 2048, data)` to reassemble an array of floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[Python.Docs]: struct - Interpret bytes as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) contains all the needed intel.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import struct
import sys


class SampleStruct(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("v", ct.c_float),
        ("t", ct.c_int),
        ("c", ct.c_char),
    )


def main(*argv):
    data = b"\x9a\x99\x99?*\x00\x00\x00A\xbe\xad\xde"
    x = SampleStruct()
    fmt = "<fic"
    fmt_size = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    x.v, x.t, x.c = struct.unpack(fmt, data[:fmt_size])
    print("Fields\n  v: {:f}\n  t: {:d}\n  c: {:s}".format(x.v, x.t, x.c.decode()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- Starting from the point where the data (*data*) was received from the socket
- The format passed to *struct.unpack* (*fmt* *arg*) tells it how the data is organized: in our case it's `"<fic"`: *float*, *int*, *char* (preceded by the *little endian* marker)
- Also calculating the size (in bytes) of data that the format requires: it's 9 (4 + 4 + 1). *data* has 12 bytes, so ignoring the last 3, otherwise *struct.unpack* will spit *struct.error*
- Check [[SO]: Python struct.pack() behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37990060/4788546) for more details on *struct.pack*

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048822543]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Fields
>   v: 1.200000
>   t: 42
>   c: A
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Awesome. But when I use `struct.decode()` to decode my received data: `b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x07\xd0\x00\x00'` , python fails to decode this into (1,2,2000). Any guess ? I also swapped `"<fic"` with `fmt = "iii"`
`

Comment: @PeDro: in that case you would need `struct.unpack_from(">HII", b)` (note that the 2 rightmost bytes **will be ignored**).