# Ctypes-String pointers

Tags: python, pointers, dll, ctypes

This python code calls a dll(Created in LabVIEW) which returns the size of the string passed as argument.
Every time I try passing string with different size, it returns the size as "1".
I tried calling the dll in different programming languages like C,LabVIEW, it's working fine.

download link for dll file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pnYI6-SfUY3Cn6EeD4mWUO6dlEBH3DmN

```
    import ctypes
    from ctypes import windll, cdll,\
        c_wchar, c_size_t, c_ulonglong, c_wchar_p, c_void_p,\
        sizeof,\
        WinError
    try:
        dllhandle = ctypes.CDLL("Strlen.dll")
        print("Library Loaded")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Can't open DLL:",e)
    dllhandle.Strlen.argtypes = [ctypes.c_wchar_p]
    dllhandle.Strlen.restype = ctypes.c_int32
    data = "Hello"
    data_ptr = ctypes.c_wchar_p(data)
    print("Data Pointer:",data_ptr)
    length = dllhandle.Strlen(data_ptr)
    print("Data:",data)
    print("String Length:",length)
```

Can anyone help me solve this?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `SetExcursionFreeExecutionSetting` do? Also do you have the functions headers? I have an idea why it behaves like this but I want to test before making it public. Although I'm a bit reluctant executing unknown code on my *PC*. How do you call the func from other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes**:

- The *.dll* is unusable (its *DllMain* which in this case is *LVDLLStatus*, returns ***0*** - triggering [[MS.Docs]: LoadLibraryW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) to fail with *ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED*) without *LabVIEW Run-Time Engine*
- I downloaded [[NI]: LabVIEW Run-Time Engine 2017 - (64-bit) - Windows - Windows 10/8.1 64-bit/7 (SP1) 64-bit/Server 2012 R2 64-bit/Server 2008 R2 64-bit](http://www.ni.com/download/labview-run-time-engine-2017/6821/en), and after that I was able to load it

My guess was correct: the function expects a `char *` (*8bit*), while `wchar\t *` is *16bit*.

Test code (*code.py*):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from ctypes import CDLL,\
    c_int, c_char_p, c_wchar_p


WORDS = [
    "",
    "a",
    "q z",
    "asd\n",
    "12345",
    "qwertyuiop",
]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    strlen_dll = CDLL("Strlen")
    strlen_func = strlen_dll.Strlen
    strlen_func.restype = c_int
    for word in WORDS:
        print("{:s}:\n    len: {:d}".format(repr(word), len(word)))
        strlen_func.argtypes = [c_char_p]
        print("    Strlen.Strlen(c_char_p): {:d}".format(strlen_func(word.encode())))
        strlen_func.argtypes = [c_wchar_p]
        print("    Strlen.Strlen(c_wchar_p): {:d}".format(strlen_func(word)))
```

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049030000>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> '':
>     len: 0
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_char_p): 0
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_wchar_p): 0
> 'a':
>     len: 1
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_char_p): 1
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_wchar_p): 1
> 'q z':
>     len: 3
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_char_p): 3
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_wchar_p): 1
> 'asd\n':
>     len: 4
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_char_p): 4
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_wchar_p): 1
> '12345':
>     len: 5
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_char_p): 5
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_wchar_p): 1
> 'qwertyuiop':
>     len: 10
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_char_p): 10
>     Strlen.Strlen(c_wchar_p): 1
> ```

**Explanation**:

- *wchar_t* (or `unsigned short`) is used by *Win* when working with *Wide Characters*. According to [[MS.Docs]: Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/LearnWin32/working-with-strings)

  > Windows represents Unicode characters using UTF-16 encoding, in which each character is encoded as a 16-bit value.
- A *Google* search on *UTF-16* will yield lots of results, here are a couple of them:

  - [[SO]: What is Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16)
  - [[Wikipedia]: UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)
  - [[GitHub]: What everyone should know about Unicode](https://kishuagarwal.github.io/unicode.html)
  - Also check [[Wikipedia]: Code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)
- Let's take character ***A*** (hex *0x41*) for example. Since it'a a plain *ASCII*, it will be represented as a *wchar_t* like:

  - *0x00* - this byte is not required, and no code page, you can look at it like at a  padding byte
  - *0x41* - the value itself
- As seen, the 1<sup>st</sup> byte of the *wchar_t* is **0**, which is the same as the *NULL* character terminator ([[Wikipedia]: Null-terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)). So, without knowing, you're passing a string that contains such chars, and when the function encounters the 1<sup>st</sup> one, it stops
- But why does it return **1** (and not **0** as the 1<sup>st</sup> *wide char* in the string starts with a *0x00*)? It's because [[Wikipedia]: Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (and the fact that *Intel* *CPU*s and the *OS*es running on them are ***little-endian***). You should also check [[SO]: Python struct.pack() behavior (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990060/python-struct-pack-behavior/38003729#38003729) (*endianness* related section)