# Reading certain part of a .bin file (eg. from 11th 23rd): hex into int, char string. C

Tags: c, file, pointers

I want to **read eg. between 11th and 23rd number from hex .bin file** looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KJ1S.jpg, **print some parts as intiger or other parts as a name (string)**. (preferably without using any `[ ]`, only operations on pointers)

My example .bin file contains: first 4 hex numbers (blue highlight) is the length of name, then 2 numbers is name in ASCII. Next 4 numbers (blue underline) is the length of surname (red underline), and the last one is index.

My attempt: 
After loading entire .bin file to buffer exactly like presented here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/ , I miserably tried in many ways to assign parts of this buffer to variables (or a structure) and then, printf it using formatting, just to see what got assigned.

```
 char *name_length = malloc(4);
 char *pEnd;
 for(*buffer=0; *buffer<4; *buffer++) {
     sscanf(buffer, "%s", name_length);
     long int i = strtol (buffer, &pEnd, 16);
     printf("%x", i);
 }
```

Above (wrong) code prints 0000 (I imagine it is completely rotten from it's roots, though I don't know why); in case there was an elegant way to load buffer parts already to structure, here's declaration:

```
 struct student_t
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[40];
    int index;
};
```

The "closest" result I Could get is another code, which prints "2000." from my .bin file: "`02 00 00 46 2E`" which means "`2` 0 0 0 /length/ `F.` /string/"

```
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  printf("%d", buffer[i]); //it's supposed to print first 4 hex digits...
  for(int j=5; j<7; j++)
  printf("%s", &buffer[j]); //it's supposed to print from 5th to 7th...
```

Thanks a lot for all the help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that I saved your exact binary data in a file called *data.bin*, here's an example:

*code.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define FILE_NAME "data.bin"


typedef struct Record_ {
    uint32_t nameLen, surnameLen;
    char *name, *surname;
} Record;


void printRecord(Record record) {
    printf("\nPrinting record:\n  Name length: %u\n  Name: [", record.nameLen);
    if ((record.nameLen != 0) && (record.name != NULL)) {
        char *pc;
        for (pc = record.name; pc < record.name + record.nameLen; pc++) {
            printf("%c", *pc);
        }
    }
    printf("]\n  Surname length: %u\n  Surname: [", record.surnameLen);
    if ((record.surnameLen != 0) && (record.surname != NULL)) {
        char *pc;
        for (pc = record.surname; pc < record.surname + record.surnameLen; pc++) {
            printf("%c", *pc);
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");
}


void clearRecord(Record *pRecord) {
    free(pRecord->name);
    free(pRecord->surname);
    memset(pRecord, 0, sizeof(Record));
}


int readRecord(FILE *pFile, Record *pRecord) {
    size_t readBytes = fread(&pRecord->nameLen, sizeof(pRecord->nameLen), 1, pFile);
    if (pRecord->nameLen != 0) {
        pRecord->name = malloc(pRecord->nameLen);
        readBytes= fread(pRecord->name, 1, pRecord->nameLen, pFile);
    }
    readBytes = fread(&pRecord->surnameLen, sizeof(pRecord->surnameLen), 1, pFile);
    if (pRecord->surnameLen != 0) {
        pRecord->surname = malloc(pRecord->surnameLen);
        readBytes = fread(pRecord->surname, 1, pRecord->surnameLen, pFile);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r+b");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file: %d\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }
    Record record = {0, 0, NULL, NULL};
    printRecord(record);
    int ret = readRecord(fp, &record);
    if (ret)
    {
        printf("readRecord returned %d\n", ret);
        fclose(fp);
        return 2;
    }
    printRecord(record);
    clearRecord(&record);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**:

- > After loading entire .bin file to buffer exactly like presented here

  Usually, this is not a very good idea. Only read as much as you need. Imagine that you want to read 10 bytes from a file hundreds of *MiB*s large. That would be a complete waste of resources, and sometimes might even lead to crashes
- It seems that you have a simple protocol here:

  1. ***4*** bytes for *name length* - this is an `uint32_t`
  2. A variable number of bytes given by the name length for *name* - this is a `char *`, as its length is not known at compile time (you could have an array like: `char[SOME_MAX_NAME_LENGTH]` where you know for sure that in the previous field there will never be a value greater than `SOME_MAX_NAME_LENGTH`, but I like this approach better)
  3. Same thing from ***#1.*** applied for *surname length*
  4. Same thing from ***#2.*** applied for *surname*

  This maps over the `Record` structure (yes the member order is not important, only the initialization order). Things could be taken even further, since the data for *surname* is a duplicate of the one for *name*, there could have been an inner structure containing the *name* data, and `Record` to contain only an array with 2 elements of that structure. 
  But even if things would be simpler that way (and also the code in functions would be shorter - without duplication), I didn't do it because it would probably be less obvious
- `printRecord` - displays `Record` data in a user-friendly manner (you can notice the pointer logic here when `printf`ing the characters individually)
- `clearRecord` - frees the memory occupied by the `char *` members and initializes everything to ***0***
- `readRecord` - reads data from file and populates the record

  - It does **not** have any error handling, since code is already pretty long. But you should **always check and handle errors** (function return codes: e.g. `fread`)
  - Be careful when reconstructing (integer) values from individual bytes, as you might get unexpected results due to *endianness*. Check [[SO]: Python struct.pack() behavior
    (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990060/python-struct-pack-behavior/38003729#38003729) (or of course, *Google*) for more info on this topic
  - Read 4 bytes for the size, then (allocate and) read "*size*" bytes for the string (I might be wrong here, but I don't think that `sscanf` (functions family) is supposed to work with binary data (except for strings))

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q052085090]> gcc code.c -o code.exe && ./code.exe
>
> Printing record:
>   Name length: 0
>   Name: []
>   Surname length: 0
>   Surname: []
>
> Printing record:
>   Name length: 2
>   Name: [F.]
>   Surname length: 13
>   Surname: [MurrayAbraham]
> ```

Comment: I'll just post cpp check report (though the method is very educating, thanks a lot!): `(warning) %d in format string (no. 1) requires 'int' but the argument type is 'unsigned int'. (warning) %d in format string (no. 1) requires 'int' but the argument type is 'unsigned int'. [invalidPrintfArgType_sint]
(warning) Size of pointer 'pRecord' used instead of size of its data. This is likely to lead to a buffer overflow. You probably intend to write 'sizeof(*pRecord)'. [pointerSize]
(style) Variable 'readBytes' is assigned a value that is never used. [unreadVariable]`
Thanks a lot!

Comment: in function clearRecord(), there should be `memset(pRecord, 0, sizeof(*pRecord));` instead of "pRecord". (based on cppcheck)

Comment: Thank you for the note. It was a typo (that could lead to segfaults if  `clearRecord`  would be applied repeatedly on the same object).

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` is not the correct tool to use for processing binary data like this.

You will get far better results working from something that looks like your last section of code, where you index each character in the buffer directly, and process it on a character by character basis.

Note that this is written assuming buffer is a pointer to characters, not a character array.

What you'll need to do is read four characters to get the length:

```
struct student_t result;
int length = 0;
int i;
// Progress backwards down data since it's stored "little endian"
for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
{
     length = (length << 8) + (buffer[i] & 255);
}
```

We've just consumed four bytes, move the buffer pointer forward to skip over them:

```
buffer += 4;
```

We have the length, and our buffer pointer now addresses the first character of the name.  Read that many characters and save them:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    result.name[i] = *buffer++;
}
// Add a NUL byte to terminate the string.
result.name[i] = '\0';
```

That'll read the name, and in so doing it's moved the buffer pointer to address the first byte of the next length value.  All you then do is reset length to zero, and repeat the above to read in the surname.