# Struct unpack on win32file.DeviceIoControl

Tags: python, struct, pywin32, deviceiocontrol

I am trying to understand and work with win32file. I need to grab USN Journals and having a hard time understanding code snippets I found online. This is the code snippet I found -

```
format = 'qqqqqLLLLqqqqq'
length = struct.calcsize(format)
out_buffer = win32file.DeviceIoControl(volh, winioctlcon.FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA, None, length)
data = struct.unpack(format, out_buffer)
```

Now I am really rusty when it comes to C and it's structures. What I have understood for now is `format` is  96 bytes buffer and it'll get the output from `DeviceIoControl`

So I tried to change the format to `'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ'` to see what happens(to see because I am kind of clueless what might actually happen) and it turns out I got a larger `out_buffer` this time. So I thought to unpack it -

```
struct.unpack(format, out_buffer)
```

And surprise to me, I got -

```
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 152
```

So I added another 'Q' to increase the size and got the same result. I don't understand why 'qqqqqLLLLqqqqq' works and 'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ' does not. So my questions are -

- My understanding was we can unpack if buffer was larger than the output so why doesn't the unpack work?
- Would I have to remember these formats every-time I want to get something out from DeviceIoControl?

Pointing me out to resources would also be an added bonus as I need to build on the code to read USN Journals and I don't think hit-and-try is going to get me anywhere

Comment: What does *volh*'s  creation process looks like (*CreateFile* call)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's split the problem in smaller pieces and take each one at a time.

- *win32file* module is part of [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) which is a *Python* wrapper over *WinAPI*s

  - Unfortunately, it doesn't have an official doc page (or I'm not aware of one), so below is the best that I could find (I've been using this for years). An alternative method that never fails (but it's less appealing) is looking directly at the code
  - [[ActiveState.Docs]: win32file.DeviceIoControl](https://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32file__DeviceIoControl_meth.html) is a wrapper over [[MS.Docs]: DeviceIoControl function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol)
- *DeviceIoControl* acts differently, depending on the *dwIoControlCode* (2<sup>nd</sup> argument). For *FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA*, it fills a buffer with volume specific data. From [[MS.Docs]: FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA IOCTL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_get_ntfs_volume_data):

  > *lpOutBuffer* 
  > A pointer to the output buffer, an [NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365256(v=vs.140).aspx) (@CristiFati: **!!! Broken *URL* !!!**) structure. The file record associated with the file identifier specified in the input buffer is returned in this buffer. Refer to the Remarks section of the documentation for the **NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER** structure for specific information on how to determine the correct size of this buffer.

  Here's an alternative to the above broken *URL*: [[MSDN]: NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa365256). As I'm not sure for how long will it be valid, I'm pasting the structure definition below (from *Windows Kits **8.1***: *winioctl.h* (line #*4987*)):

  ```c
  typedef struct {

      LARGE_INTEGER VolumeSerialNumber;
      LARGE_INTEGER NumberSectors;
      LARGE_INTEGER TotalClusters;
      LARGE_INTEGER FreeClusters;
      LARGE_INTEGER TotalReserved;
      DWORD BytesPerSector;
      DWORD BytesPerCluster;
      DWORD BytesPerFileRecordSegment;
      DWORD ClustersPerFileRecordSegment;
      LARGE_INTEGER MftValidDataLength;
      LARGE_INTEGER MftStartLcn;
      LARGE_INTEGER Mft2StartLcn;
      LARGE_INTEGER MftZoneStart;
      LARGE_INTEGER MftZoneEnd;

  } NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER, *PNTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER;
  ```
- [[Python 3.Docs]: struct - Interpret bytes as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module, is used for conversions between binary and "normal" data. It contains all the format characters meanings (*q*, *Q*, *L*, ...), and much more. You could also take a look at [[SO]: Python struct.pack() behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990060/python-struct-pack-behavior) for more (practical) details

After going over the above materials, things should become clearer.

A couple of notes:

- If one doesn't know what a function does (returns), they should probably don't use it (without reading the manual, of course). Although nowadays, both *Win* (which always had a lot of restrictions for the regular user) and *Nix* "protect users from themselves" (e.g.: *root* login no longer allowed, write protect *%SystemDrive%*, ...)
- The attempts (trial and error) show some lack of experience (probably everyone does it at some point, the key is not to rely solely on it)
- "*Would I have to remember these formats every-time I want to get something out from DeviceIoControl*"?

  - Again, if not knowing that a function does, what's the reason for calling it? If you meant learning *NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER* by heart, it's definitely not the case. You should know its structure only when using it (and as you've noticed there are some places that you can get it from - including this very post :) )
- "*My understanding was we can unpack if buffer was larger than the output so why doesn't the unpack work?*"

  - Your understanding is correct. But *win32file.DeviceIoControl* seems to **sometimes** (probably when reaching 1<sup>st</sup> ***NULL*** after *96* bytes) truncate the output buffer when passing a value greater than the expected one (via *length* argument). When passing a smaller one, it will fail (as expected)

I've also prepared a dummy *Python* example.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import struct
import win32file
import win32api
import win32con
import winioctlcon


VOLUME_LETTER = "E"

FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0080
FILE_EXECUTE = 0x0020

vol_data_buf_fmt = "qqqqqLLLLqqqqq"  # This is the format that matches NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER definition (96 bytes). Note: Instead of each 'q' you could also use 'Ll' as 'LARGE_INTEGER' is an union

BINARY_FORMAT_LIST = [
    vol_data_buf_fmt,
    "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ",
]


def print_formats():  # Dummy func
    print("Formats and lengths:")
    for format in BINARY_FORMAT_LIST:
        print("    {:s}: {:d}".format(format, struct.calcsize(format)))


def main():
    #print_formats()
    vol_unc_name = "\\\\.\\{:s}:".format(VOLUME_LETTER)
    print("volume: ", vol_unc_name)
    access_flags = FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_EXECUTE  # Apparently, doesn't work without FILE_EXECUTE
    share_flags = win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE  # Doesn't work withou FILE_SHARE_WRITE
    creation_flags = win32con.OPEN_EXISTING
    attributes_flags = win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
    vol_handle = win32file.CreateFile(vol_unc_name, access_flags, share_flags, None, creation_flags, attributes_flags, None)

    buf_len = struct.calcsize(vol_data_buf_fmt)
    for i in [buf_len]:
        print("    Passing a buffer size of: {:d}".format(i))
        buf = win32file.DeviceIoControl(vol_handle, winioctlcon.FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA, None, i)
        print("    DeviceIocontrol returned a {:d} bytes long {:}".format(len(buf), type(buf)))
        out = struct.unpack_from(vol_data_buf_fmt, buf)
        print("\n    NumberSectors: {:}\n    TotalClusters: {:}\n    BytesPerCluster: {:}".format(out[1], out[2], out[6]))
    win32api.CloseHandle(vol_handle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053318932>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> volume:  \\.\E:
>     Passing a buffer size of: 96
>     DeviceIocontrol returned a 96 bytes long <class 'bytes'>
>
>     NumberSectors: 494374911
>     TotalClusters: 61796863
>     BytesPerCluster: 4096
> ```

Needless to say that multiplying *TotalClusters* by *BytesPerCluster*, I get the correct bytes number (as reported by *Win*) for my *E:* drive.

Comment: Thanks @CristiFati. Actually, with a bit of hit and try and research, I was able to find the resources mentioned in your comment and was thinking of answering my own question if nobody answered it but you have

Comment: "protect users from themselves" as you said so I knew the risks I was getting into while poking around with these commands

Comment: "Every attempt simply expresses lack of experience" but attempt adds up to the experience, which in turn helped me to discover these docs

Comment: I can query through the journal now but I need to build path to parent file, this is where I am stuck currently. What I have found out is there are to ways to get this to work, one is going through the MFT(I don't want that) and the other is opening file with File Reference Number. Can you help me with the second one?

Comment: I'm afraid that my knowledge on "*File Reference Number*". Is somewhere close to 0. So without some code samples I can't do anything. But, wouldn't that be a different question (cause the code from this one is related to volume properties rather than volume changes)?