# Output of crc32b in PHP is not equal to Python

Tags: php, python, crc

I'm trying to convert `PHP` snippet into `Python3` code but outputs of `print` and `echo` are different.

You can see it in the step 1.

Do you know where is the problem? I'm attaching input arrays too but I think they are equal.

```
�W2+ vs ee7523b2
```

**EDIT**

When I switch raw from TRUE to FALSE, outputs of 1st step are the same. `$d = strrev(hash("crc32b", $d, FALSE)) . $d`

But the problem is that I have to convert PHP to Python, not the opposite because, then I'm usit in the step 2 which I need to have equal output.

**PHP OUTPUT (CMD)**

```
0 ->    1   1   100 EUR 20190101    11111111                Faktúra 1   SK6807200002891987426353        0   0
1 -> �W2+   1   1   100 EUR 20190101    11111111                Faktúra 1   SK6807200002891987426353        0   0
2 -> 00004e00007715c242b04d5014490af1445dd61c1527ddc5f4461ca5886caf63fd8fbcf7df69c2035760ecb28d8171efdb409c0206996498ea7921e715172e60c210f923f070079ffba40000
```

**PYTHON OUTPUT**

```
-------
0 ->    1   1   100 EUR 20190101    11111111                Faktúra 1   SK6807200002891987426353        0   0
1 -> ee7523b2   1   1   100 EUR 20190101    11111111                Faktúra 1   SK6807200002891987426353        0   0
2 -> b'00006227515c7830302762275c783030325c7865305c7864386a34585c7862346d5c7838665c7865625c7863315c786266625c7839625c786339675c786332785c7831645c7862392c415c7862625c7831645c78663770365c786463735c786236572d606c225c7865355c7865635c7831345c7863655c786331205c7830635c7831315c7861375c7839345c7864665c7865635c7830365c7831652c22265c7866355c7862335c7866345c78616145585c7861625c7866395c7839615c7839645c7865645c7864625c7830305c7864355c7861643b5c7865365f5c7866645c786533405c78303027'
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$suma = "100";
$datum = "20190101";
$varsym = "11111111";
$konsym = "";
$specsym = "";
$poznamka = "Faktúra";
$iban = "SK6807200002891987426353";
$swift = "";

$d = implode("\t", array(
    0 => '',
    1 => '1',
    2 => implode("\t", array(
        true,
        $suma,                      // SUMA
        'EUR',                      // JEDNOTKA
        $datum,                 // DATUM
        $varsym,                    // VARIABILNY SYMBOL
        $konsym,                        // KONSTANTNY SYMBOL
        $specsym,                       // SPECIFICKY SYMBOL
        '',
        $poznamka,                  // POZNAMKA
        '1',
        $iban,  // IBAN
        $swift,                 // SWIFT
        '0',
        '0'
    ))
));
// 0
echo "0 -> ".$d."\n";
$d = strrev(hash("crc32b", $d, TRUE)) . $d;
// 1
echo "1 -> ".$d."\n";
$x = proc_open("/usr/bin/xz '--format=raw' '--lzma1=lc=3,lp=0,pb=2,dict=128KiB' '-c' '-'", [0 => ["pipe", "r"], 1 => ["pipe", "w"]], $p);
fwrite($p[0], $d);
fclose($p[0]);
$o = stream_get_contents($p[1]);
fclose($p[1]);
proc_close($x);

$d = bin2hex("\x00\x00" . pack("v", strlen($d)) . $o);
// 2
echo "2 -> ".$d."\n";
?>
```

**PYTHON**

```
    def crc32b(x):
        h = zlib.crc32(x)
        x='%08X' % (h & 0xffffffff,)
        return x.lower()

    t = "\t"
    gen = t.join(["1",
                  "100", # SAME VARIABLES 
                  "EUR",
                  "20190101",
                  "11111111",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "",
                  "Faktúra",
                  "1",
                  "SK6807200002891987426353",
                  "",
                  "0",
                  "0"]
                 )

    d = t.join([
        "", "1", gen])
    # 0
    print(f"0 -> {d}")
    hashD = crc32b(d.encode()) # OK

    hashD = hashD[::-1]
    # hashD = str(binascii.unhexlify(hashD))
    d = hashD + d
    # 1
    print(f"1 -> {d}")
    args = shlex.split("xz '--format=raw' '--lzma1=lc=3,lp=0,pb=2,dict=128KiB' -c -")
    process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate(d.encode())

    pack = "\x00\x00" + str(struct.pack("H", len(d))) + str(output[0])

    d = binascii.hexlify(pack.encode())
    # 2
    print(f"2 -> {d}")
```

Comment: How would you do that? I've added step 2. Those have to be equal.

Comment: @aws_apprentice It's crc32b not crc32 and zlib is used inside the function as you can see

Answer (score 1):

Didn't work with *PHP*. 
According to [[Python.Docs]: zlib.crc32(data[, value])](https://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Computes a CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check) checksum of *data*. The result is an **unsigned 32-bit integer**.

You are making a confusion between:

- Its value - which can also be seen as an *ASCII* string of **length 4**
- The textual representation of its value (in **base *16***) - which is a string of **length 8**

> ```
> >>> crc = 0x2B3257EE  # The value returned by zlib.crc32 for your text
> >>> type(crc), crc
> (<class 'int'>, 724719598)
> >>>
> >>> [chr((crc >> shift_bits) & 0xFF) for shift_bits in [0, 8, 16, 24]]
> ['î', 'W', '2', '+']
> ```

**Notes**:

- One way to do it is converting each of the number's 4 bytes into a *char*
- To get a byte from the *uint32* value, the *uint32* must be shifted to the right ([[Python.Wiki]: BitwiseOperators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)) by the order of that *byte* in the value (***[3, 2, 1, 0]***) multiplied by ***8*** (number of bits in a byte)

  - Also, to get rid of the unwanted bytes (any of them except the right-most one), the resulting value is also *and*ed with *0xFF* (*255*)
- Due to *little endian*ness, the bytes are converted to *char*s in reversed order (from right to left)
- The 1<sup>st</sup> *char* (***'î'***) looks different, but it's just a matter of representation (in my console *vs.* yours)

Integrating it into your code, you need to modify your *crc32b* function (and also remove any further processing on *hashD*) to:

```py
def crc32b(x):
    crc = zlib.crc32(x)
    return "".join([chr((crc >> shift_bits) & 0xFF) for shift_bits in [0, 8, 16, 24]])
```

For more details on this general topic, check [[SO]: Python struct.pack() behavior (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38003729/4788546).

---

#### Update *#0*

Adding the version that starts from the *hex* representation:

> ```
> >>> crc = 0x2B3257EE
> >>> crc_hex = "{:08X}".format(crc)
> >>> crc_hex
> '2B3257EE'
> >>>
> >>> list(reversed([chr(int(crc_hex[2 * i] + crc_hex[2 * i + 1], 16)) for i in range(len(crc_hex) // 2)]))
> ['î', 'W', '2', '+']
> ```

- From my *PoV*, this is uglier, also it's inefficient (many back and forth conversions), but posting anyway as some folks have trouble working on bit operations
- The key point is to handle 2 *hex* *char*s at a time, and only reverse after conversion

Answer (score 0):

you just have to remove the 3rd argument of the function `hash()`

if you set this argument to true, hash will return raw binary data and php is trying to parse it as a text string whereas you are expecting a hexadecimal result

Comment: Thanks but I need to edit Python code to get the same result, not the opposite. How would you do that? It's a part of a bigger script and I need to use the output on the other line.