# How are the different from_buffer() methods implemented for ctypes types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

In the python `ctypes` module's `__init__.py` file, the ctypes types are defined as sub-classes of the `_SimpleCData`. Such as:

```
from _ctypes import _SimpleCData
...
class c_long(_SimpleCData):
    _type_ = "l"
```

And the `_SimpleCData` has the class method of `from_buffer()`.

So I think this `from_buffer()` method should be also inherited by the child-classes.

But it turns out those methods are different because they are at different addresses:

```
>>> ctypes.c_long.from_buffer
<built-in method from_buffer of _ctypes.PyCSimpleType object at 0x16f8fb0>
>>> ctypes._SimpleCData.from_buffer
<built-in method from_buffer of _ctypes.PyCSimpleType object at 0x7f19f9b09ae0>
```

How/where are the different `from_buffer()` methods get attached to each `ctypes` type class?

### ADD 1 - 9:24 AM 12/28/2021

I use `c_int.from_address()` and `c_char.from_address()` on the same address, and different values are interpreted. So these methods are indeed different.

```
>>> cint =ctypes.c_int.from_address(0x2bc9d60)
>>> cchar =ctypes.c_char.from_address(0x2bc9d60)
>>> cchar2 = ctypes.c_char.from_address(0x2bc9d61) # next byte
>>> hex(ctypes.addressof(cint))
'0x2bc9d60'
>>> hex(ctypes.addressof(cchar))
'0x2bc9d60'
>>> hex(ctypes.addressof(cchar2))
'0x2bc9d61'

>>> cint.value   # *(int *)(0x2bc9d60)  = 0x116 = 278
278
>>> cchar.value  # *(char *)(0x2bc9d60) = 0x16
b'\x16'
>>> cchar2.value # *(char *)(0x2bc9d61) = 0x1
b'\x01'
```

So `c_int` takes 4 bytes and `c_char` takes only 1 byte.

How is this polymorphism achieved?

Comment: The addresses shown are the addresses of the different instances of `PyCSimpleType` objects, not the `from_buffer` method.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for pointing that out. It seems the `from_buffer()` method roots from the `_ctypes.PyCSimpleType`. So are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit convoluted so bear with me. In *_ctypes.c* (version 3.8.5), there is on line 5788:

```c
    Py_TYPE(&Simple_Type) = &PyCSimpleType_Type;
    Simple_Type.tp_base = &PyCData_Type;
    if (PyType_Ready(&Simple_Type) < 0)
        return NULL;
    Py_INCREF(&Simple_Type);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "_SimpleCData", (PyObject *)&Simple_Type);
```

This exposes the address of `Simple_Type` as the name `_SimpleCData`. `Simple_Type` (a.k.a. `_SimpleCData` to the Python world) also inherits from `PyCDataType` (more on that later). First, the definition of `Simple_Type` is on line 5040:

```c
static PyTypeObject Simple_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    "_ctypes._SimpleCData",
    sizeof(CDataObject),                        /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                                          /* tp_itemsize */
    0,                                          /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                                          /* tp_vectorcall_offset */
    0,                                          /* tp_getattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_async */
    (reprfunc)&Simple_repr,                     /* tp_repr */
    &Simple_as_number,                          /* tp_as_number */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                                          /* tp_hash */
    0,                                          /* tp_call */
    0,                                          /* tp_str */
    0,                                          /* tp_getattro */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattro */
    &PyCData_as_buffer,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE, /* tp_flags */
    "XXX to be provided",                       /* tp_doc */
    (traverseproc)PyCData_traverse,             /* tp_traverse */
    (inquiry)PyCData_clear,                     /* tp_clear */
    0,                                          /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                                          /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                                          /* tp_iter */
    0,                                          /* tp_iternext */
    Simple_methods,                             /* tp_methods */
    0,                                          /* tp_members */
    Simple_getsets,                             /* tp_getset */
    0,                                          /* tp_base */
    0,                                          /* tp_dict */
    0,                                          /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                                          /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                                          /* tp_dictoffset */
    (initproc)Simple_init,                      /* tp_init */
    0,                                          /* tp_alloc */
    GenericPyCData_new,                         /* tp_new */
    0,                                          /* tp_free */
};
```

This is in essence a metaclass used to define new classes. One of the members of this structure (with the comment /* tp_methods */) references the following array defined on line 4996:

```c
static PyMethodDef Simple_methods[] = {
    { "__ctypes_from_outparam__", Simple_from_outparm, METH_NOARGS, },
    { NULL, NULL },
```

This should be a list of methods that classes created by this metaclass will have. But wait! That is only a single method. Let's look at the class it inherits from, `PyCSimpleType_Type` on line 2327:

```c
PyTypeObject PyCSimpleType_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    "_ctypes.PyCSimpleType",                                    /* tp_name */
    0,                                          /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                                          /* tp_itemsize */
    0,                                          /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                                          /* tp_vectorcall_offset */
    0,                                          /* tp_getattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_async */
    0,                                          /* tp_repr */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_number */
    &CDataType_as_sequence,             /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                                          /* tp_hash */
    0,                                          /* tp_call */
    0,                                          /* tp_str */
    0,                                          /* tp_getattro */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattro */
    0,                                          /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE, /* tp_flags */
    "metatype for the PyCSimpleType Objects",           /* tp_doc */
    0,                                          /* tp_traverse */
    0,                                          /* tp_clear */
    0,                                          /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                                          /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                                          /* tp_iter */
    0,                                          /* tp_iternext */
    PyCSimpleType_methods,                      /* tp_methods */
    0,                                          /* tp_members */
    0,                                          /* tp_getset */
    0,                                          /* tp_base */
    0,                                          /* tp_dict */
    0,                                          /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                                          /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                                          /* tp_dictoffset */
    0,                                          /* tp_init */
    0,                                          /* tp_alloc */
    PyCSimpleType_new,                                  /* tp_new */
    0,                                          /* tp_free */
};
```

The methods it brings along are `PyCSimpleType_methods` defined on line 2318:

```c
static PyMethodDef PyCSimpleType_methods[] = {
    { "from_param", PyCSimpleType_from_param, METH_O, from_param_doc },
    { "from_address", CDataType_from_address, METH_O, from_address_doc },
    { "from_buffer", CDataType_from_buffer, METH_VARARGS, from_buffer_doc, },
    { "from_buffer_copy", CDataType_from_buffer_copy, METH_VARARGS, from_buffer_copy_doc, },
    { "in_dll", CDataType_in_dll, METH_VARARGS, in_dll_doc},
    { NULL, NULL },
};
```

So it appears that the mataclass builds a new class including all of the methods specified by the `tp_methods` member of the metaclass's *struct* definition and its base classes. **This should result in the `from_buffer` method having the same address for all objects for all classes created by the metaclass.**

Referring back to your post:

```py
>>> ctypes.c_long.from_buffer
<built-in method from_buffer of _ctypes.PyCSimpleType object at 0x16f8fb0>
>>> ctypes._SimpleCData.from_buffer
<built-in method from_buffer of _ctypes.PyCSimpleType object at 0x7f19f9b09ae0>
```

I now believe you are misinterpreting what is being output. **0x16f8fb0 and 0x7f19f9b09ae0 are not the addresses of the `from_buffer` methods, which should be the same for both objects, but rather the addresses of the `ctypes.PyCSimpleType` objects themselves that are implementing these types.**

Mark Tolonen had it right, but in case you needed convincing (I did too) ...

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). 
Also listing [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (v3.9.9) This is Python version 3.9.9](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/v3.9.9) (*v3.9.9* is the version I'm going to use as an example). Any (*Python*) source file that I'm going to mention will be relative to this.

I'm not going to insist on different method addresses as it was already covered: it's not the method address (a method address wouldn't make any sense in *Python*) but the class object's (that encapsulate the method).

All the simple *C* type wrappers are defined ***Lib/ctypes/__init__.py*** (as already stated), as subclasses of *_SimpleCData*. The only thing that differs among them is an **apparently minor detail: the *_type_* class field**. Check [[Python.Docs]: struct - Interpret strings as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#module-struct) for possible values.

The "real magic" happens in ***Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c*** (mostly). Let's work things out from top to bottom (concept-wise, not by position in the file). I'm not going to list line numbers (as one could search for any identifier name that will be mentioned):

- *CTypes* is based on (external) *FFI*
- ***Simple_Type*** is the class implementation for *_SimpleCData* (which is its display name)
- ***PyCSimpleType_Type*** (*_ctypes.PyCSimpleType*) is *Simple_Type* (*_SimpleCData*)'s **meta class** (set via *Py_SET_TYPE*). Example:

  > ```py
  > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q070496724]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe"
  > Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
  > Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  > >>> import ctypes as ct
  > >>> import _ctypes as _ct
  > >>>
  > >>> SCD = _ct._SimpleCData
  > >>> SCD
  > <class '_ctypes._SimpleCData'>
  > >>> dir(SCD)
  > ['__bool__', '__class__', '__ctypes_from_outparam__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_b_base_', '_b_needsfree_', '_objects', 'value']
  > >>> SCD.__class__
  > <class '_ctypes.PyCSimpleType'>
  > ```
- *PyCSimpleType_methods* are (some of) *PyCSimpleType_Type*'s methods
- ***CDataType_from_address*** and ***CDataType_from_buffer*** are the 2 method implementations
- Both of the above methods rely on ***PyCData_AtAddress*** (note the ***type*** argument). The key line is:

  ```c
  pd = (CDataObject *)((PyTypeObject *)type)->tp_alloc((PyTypeObject *)type, 0);
  ```
- Going back to *PyCSimpleType_Type*, its instance creator method is ***PyCSimpleType_new***: **this is called when creating *_SimpleCData* class objects, not their instances**

  - Notice the ***_type_*** member (although the final name will differ). Does it ring a bell?
  - You can also check ***SIMPLE_TYPE_CHARS*** for a familiar set of *char*s
- Things can be taken deeper (*Modules/_ctypes/stgdict.c*), but I think it's enough

So, the *c_** classes (simple *C* type wrappers) don't have separate implementations for those methods, but the implementation lies in their base (meta) class, and they have a different attribute value (which complies with *OOP*'s inheritance concept).

I created a small example.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import sys


def test_from_addr(addr):
    print("\nTest from_address(0x{:016X}) method for various simple C types".format(addr))
    types = (
        ct.c_ulonglong,
        ct.c_uint,
        ct.c_ushort,
        ct.c_ubyte,
    )

    for typ in types:
        print("{:s} representation: {:}".format(typ.__name__, hex(typ.from_address(addr).value)))


def _simple_c_type_factory(spec):
    class SimpleCType(ct._SimpleCData):
        _type_ = spec

    return SimpleCType


def test_simple_types(addr):
    print("\nTest simple C type instances creation from address: 0x{:016X}".format(addr))
    specs = "QLIHB"
    for spec in specs:
        typ = _simple_c_type_factory(spec)
        print("{:s} representation: {:}".format(spec, hex(typ.from_address(addr).value)))


def main(*argv):
    ull0 = ct.c_ulonglong(0x1234567890ABCDEF)
    aull0 = ct.addressof(ull0)

    test_from_addr(aull0)
    test_simple_types(aull0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q070496724]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>
> Test from_address(0x00000199612CAE08) method for various simple C types
> c_ulonglong representation: 0x1234567890abcdef
> c_ulong representation: 0x90abcdef
> c_ushort representation: 0xcdef
> c_ubyte representation: 0xef
>
> Test simple C type instances creation from address: 0x00000199612CAE08
> Q representation: 0x1234567890abcdef
> L representation: 0x90abcdef
> I representation: 0x90abcdef
> H representation: 0xcdef
> B representation: 0xef
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- I only used unsigned types because the memory representation is clearer (things are exactly the same for signed ones)
- The results are a bit surprising (the part at the end matches). This is because my *CPU* (*Intel pc064*) is *little endian*. On a *big endian* system  things would be a lot clearer. Check more details on this topic: [[SO]: Python struct.pack() behavior (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990060/python-struct-pack-behavior/38003729#38003729).